# Google Chrome is not rendering fonts properly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-devtools

Hello i am working on this website bamboo-intranet.com . Recently i noticed that the website font in the menu is not loading good on google chrome browser, it gets stuck without any styles, i have been trying to solve this problem but couldn't find whats wrong. I would like to know if someone know what could be my problem. I  am also adding the css styles I use for the menu  and the html syntax so you can see if something is wrong.

Screenshot:
[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Bamboo - Intranet Software</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Pequeñas, medianas y grandes compañías han implementado Bamboo Intranet como su plataforma de comunicación interna. Organizando, facilitando y agilizando dramáticamente las labores del día a día.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Bamboo - Intranet Software" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Pequeñas, medianas y grandes compañías han implementado Bamboo Intranet como su plataforma de comunicación interna. Organizando, facilitando y agilizando dramáticamente las labores del día a día." />     
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://bamboo-intranet.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://bamboo-intranet.com/img/fbthumb.jpg"/>
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skins/tango/skin.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sprites.css" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://bamboo-intrantet/img/fbthumb.jpg" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <header class="step0">
        <a href="http://bamboo-intranet.com/"><div class="logo"><img src="images/logo-bamboo.png" alt="Bamboo Intranet Software" /><h1>Bamboo - Intranet Software</h1></div></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#container">CARACTERÍSTICAS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#screenshots">SCREENSHOTS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#beta_test">VERSIÓN DE PRUEBA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- /HEADER -->
```

CSS Code:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 42px 10px 0;
    width: auto;

}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
     list-style: none;
     float: left;
     font-size: 13px;
     color: #525252;
     margin-right: 5px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 14px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #767676;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    font-family: 'Roboto', arial;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try being more specific,

```
nav ul li  {
     list-style: none;
     float: left;
     font-size: 13px;
     color: #525252;
     margin-right: 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 14px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #767676;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    font-family: 'Roboto', arial;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

If that does not solve your problem use classes, if that does not solve your problem use the inspect element option in your browser and see what CSS is acting on the HTML

can you post a link to the site?

Comment: hello, the link is www.bamboo-intranet.com i actually had my styles like that but changed in order to test it.

Comment: Hi, Looks like the link are working tested them in my browser they look 100% correct nice job on the site looks good although I don't understand Spanish. It might be a long shot but be sure to check out normalizer in future it might help with issues like this.here is the link: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Cool Man glad you got it working and got your boss off your back, Really dont know why that JS made it freak out but it works so... Nice job really awesome site! keep well